# Argument error with initialize

Tags: ruby, initialization

I am trying the code below:

```
class A
  def initialize foo = nil
    super
  end
end

A.new
```

When I run it, it raises an error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` at the `super` line. Why does this raise an error? I haven't passed any argument to `new` or `super`, and am not sure why. If I omit the optional argument signature `foo = nil`, the error goes away.

The code above with `super` might not make much sense, but in actual use, `A` is a subclass of `Hash`, and I have a block passed to `super`.

Comment: Super by itself automatically calls the parent with the arguments provided to itself

Comment: @Mahan That is right. And I haven't passed any argument.

Comment: @7stud I don't get what you mean. Particularly, I don't get why you have "a parameter was assigned a default arg" and "an arg was passed in" joined by "or." Those two things are independent of each other.

Comment: I think you need to use `super()`

Comment: @Mahan That would be a way to resolve the error, but I want to know why the error was raised.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me. I'm not sure what the confusion is. Regardless of whether you've explicitly passed an argument, the method received an argument, so it gets forwarded up via `super` since you've not used the more explicit `super()`. It's very easy to circumvent this behavior with `super()`; however, if the default were that only explicitly passed arguments were forwarded with `super`, there would be no way to get the current behavior. You'd wind up having to manually forward all your arguments if any of them were optional.

Comment: @meagar "the method received an argument" from where?

Comment: @sawa From the default argument that you specified?

Comment: So it seems like the actual explicit call of a method like `new` (or `new()`) doesn't count for the purpose of deciding what arguments are passed, but the way it is received by the method definition counts.

Comment: Yes, this is my interpretation. Within the method there is no concept of which arguments were explicitly sent to the method, and which are defaults. I think it would be very surprising if you invoked `initialize(name, age=10); super; end` and only `name` were forwarded via `super`.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, For those of us who are too stupid, could you explain  to us how the question you linked to is a duplicate answer? In your explanation, please note that the topic of this question pertains to default arguments, and the question you linked to doesn't even employ a default argument.  Also consider: if you cannot discern the topic of a question, is it really your place to go around marking questions as duplicates?

Comment: super doesn't care whether a default value was assigned to a parameter variable OR an arg was passed in and assigned to the parameter variable...because super passes parameter variables--not arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It raises because when you call super without specifying arguments, it calls the parent method with the same arguments that the caller received.
In your case, calling just `super` is the same as calling `super(foo)`, and the `Object` class (the parent object of `A`) contains no initializer receiving a parameter.
I believe you expect the behavior from this code:

```
class A
  def initialize foo = nil
    super() # <= note the empty parentesis
  end
end

A.new
```

It's important to note that an argument with default value is still an argument, even if the default value is nil. A default value only means that callers can call it without specifying the argument, not that the parameter does not exists. For the Ruby VM, your initializer will always have the `foo` argument.

You can verify this behavior writing the following code in a irb session:

```
def foo(bar = nil); end
method(:foo).parameters # => [[:opt, :bar]]
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not explain why it still raises an error when `A.new()` is called at the end instead of `A.new` in my original code.

Comment: It still raises because only the caller context think there is no argument - inside the method there will always be at least one argument.

Comment: I edited my answer again including info about this.

Comment: Your "even if the default value is nil" is misleading. It is not relevant.

Comment: And regarding your last part, it shows that the method is able to distinguish optional arguments from obligatory ones. That does not say anything toward whether optional arguments are counted towards the argument signature.

Comment: I don't think "even if the default value is nil" is misleading and not relevant. Ruby treats undefined values differently than nil values. A nil parameter is still a parameter, and so it is sent to the superclass when calling super. In this case, calling `A.new` is the same as `A.new(nil)`. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to explain this in a different way.